GPU not found in Blender in 24.04
I can see there is a proper GPU driver selected under " Additional Drivers ". I am using the Flatpak version of Blender 4.0.2. Under Blender Preferences > System, this is what I see.



I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 graphics card and Ryzen 5600H processor. Thanks.
Edit 1:
Found the issue, it works when I use the download from Blender.org instead of Flatpak


As OP discovered, the issue is in fact the Flatpak, it didn't work or support CUDA capacity in the flatpak.
